# Caching templates in memory

Tags: php, caching, web-applications

Until now i had only saw that website views/templates were cached in directories/files.

But today i see a new open source Cache Component which saves all the Views/Templates in RAM.

I am not sure if it's good practice or bad. Can you please suggest how should i rate this technique?

Comment: speed of memory > speed of disc.

Comment: How is ensured that the cached data is persisted over multiple requests? Does your component use an additional RAM storage backend (e.g. APC or memcached)?

Comment: @helmbert: There is no extra RAM storage.

Answer (score 2):

Caching strategies entirely depend on the specific needs of your project and the resources at your disposal. Caching in memory is generally far more performant than caching from a disk, but you need to balance your needs and your resources.

First, ask yourself: 'Do I really need additional caching?' It's possible that you do not, and it is not worth going through the effort of setting something else up. Caching is rarely simple, even if it seems like it should be, and generally requires a fair amount of trial and error.

If the answer to the first question is 'yes', ask yourself: 'Do I have enough memory available to meet my caching needs? If not, can I afford to buy more, or buy a separate machine dedicated to in-memory caching?'

If the answer is 'yes', go for in-memory caching.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove cache from browser you can add this piece line of code in your head tag
this is bad practice but your problem will solve after add this line.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")
```

Comment: I believe this question is not about client-side caching, but rather server-side in-memory caching.